# How to get post data form using symfony 2.6

Tags: php, forms, symfony

What is the best way to retrieve post data ?

I red that it's better to use $form->handleRequest($request);

I want to make something like that but it's depreciated isn't it ?

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $var = $form->get('yourformfieldname')->getData();

    ...
}
```

But if I need to get data when the form is POST but before isValid(), how can I do that ?

WHY ? I need 2 properties of the form. With these 2 properties, I can make a querybuilder to set another properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from a submitted form before it's validated you can use something like this:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    //submitted and not validated
    $var = $form->get('yourformfieldname')->getData();
}

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

    return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
}
```

Refer to the [Symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) for more details and see the section on isSubmitted().

You do not need to use getMethod and handleRequest is not depreciated.  You may have been referring to passing the $request.  From the book 'Previously, the $request was passed to the submit method - a strategy which is deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0.'